# Using scipy to fit a damped sine wave to data

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

In my experimental project I have a droplet vibrating which acts a damped simple harmonic oscillator. I have to fit a damped sine wave onto the data to try and extract variables such as the frequency of the vibration. However I am having a bit of trouble perfecting the curve fitting. Below is the code that I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import imageio
import os
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from fractions import Fraction
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# %% Curve fitting

root = tk.Tk(); root.withdraw()  # close the tkinter root window

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()  # open file dialogue box

data=np.loadtxt(file_path, skiprows=0)  # read the data from file
time = data[:, 0]; height = data[:, 1]  # extract the time and data arrays


def myfit(t, a, b, c, phi, ho):                 # define the function
    return a*np.exp(b*t)*np.cos(c*t+phi) + ho


# perform the fit # [1,-10,100,0,2]
param, param_cov = curve_fit(myfit, time, height, maxfev=2500)

# get the standard deviations of all fit parameters from variance-co-variance matrix
stdevm = np.sqrt(np.diag(param_cov))

# generate the fit line ready for plotting
fitplot = param[0]*np.exp(param[1]*time)*np.cos(param[2]*time+param[3])+param[4]

plt.figure();plt.plot(time,height,'r.',label="data")
plt.plot(time,fitplot,'-', color ='blue', label ="fit")
plt.legend();plt.xlabel("time (seconds)");plt.ylabel("droplet height (mm)")
```

However this does no produce a very good fit. Despite the jaggedness which is expected considering the number of points the value of b is positive when it should be negative. The following graph is produced from the code above:

[image: Damped sine wave fitted]

In order to rectify this I tried rectifying the bounds as such:

```
param, param_cov = curve_fit(myfit, time, height, p0=[6, 10, 471, 1, 2], bounds=[[4, -50, 100, -10, -2], [7, 0, 1000, 10, 1]], maxfev=2500)
```

However the error below gets produced:

[image: error shown when bounds change]

I need help trying to either fixing the bounds, or is there another better way of fitting this data. Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Frankly it does not look like a bad fit. I would guess the code is working fine. You can check by passing in data (`height`) that is generated from the same functional form you are trying to fit, to see if your curve fitting can recover the parameters. I think it is just that the functional form you chose is not flexible enough to get closer to your observed points.

Comment: ah and the error seems to indicate that your initial point does not satisfy the bounds you are putting in

Comment: I would agree with you that's its not a bad fit on the whole, apart from the fact that the graph is rising exponentially not decaying. And when I try and change this so that b is negative by providing boundary conditions it doesn't plot.

Comment: Have you tried making sure that `p0` satisfies your bounds? eg set the second element of p0 that corresponds to `b` parameter to a negative number: `param, param_cov = curve_fit(myfit, time, height, p0=[6, -10, 471, 1, 2], bounds=[[4, -50, 100, -10, -2], [7, 0, 1000, 10, 1]], maxfev=2500)`

Comment: also the last element of `p0` is outside of bounds. Lastly according to the documentation bounds should a 2-tuple not a two-element array (of arrays) but I do not think it matters. but would switch if still can't get it to work just to be sure

Comment: The data does not look like there was damping. The amplitude of the oscillation around 0.08s is cleary larger than at 0.02s.

Comment: ok thanks piterbarg i'll try that. And I do believe that it looks like a damped wave.  Christian, I do believe that it looks damped as it starts on 7 and ends just under 6. The only discrepancy is the middle wave and that's because the max amplitude was seeming not recorded probably todo with the lack of data.